# How to check and add values to certain indexes of a list if conditions are met

Tags: python-3.x

```py
salary = []
for i in range(3):
    x = float(input("Enter Salary: "))
    salary.append(x)

print(("\n"), salary)

for i in range(3):
    if salary[i] <= 7500:
        salary[i] = [+2000]
        print(salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate over the list and modify the items based on a condition:

```
salary = []
for i in range(3):
    x = float(input("Enter Salary: "))
    salary.append(x)

print(f"Initial list:{salary}")

for index, value in enumerate(salary):
    if value <= 7500:
        salary[index] = value + 2000

print(f"After increase: {salary}")
```